# PostgreSQL internals composite column cardinality

Tags: postgresql, database-design, indexing, composite-key, database-indexes

**EDIT**

This is not a question about space, but about uniqueness of index, which affects the query plan.

In terms of cardinality, which index scenario is higher:

**A**

```
Table:
(
  Col1 smallint,
  Col2 smallint
)
```

where

```
Range Col1 : 0 - 1000
Range Col2 : 0 - 1000
```

and a composite index on `(Col1, Col2)`, always queried in sequence.

**B**

Table:

```
(
  Col1_2 int
)
```

where

```
Range Col1_2 : 0 - 1000^2
```

and a single index on `(Col1_2)` with stores and queries combining the Col1 and Col2 components.

What I am basically asking is, is it better (as in index usage) to combine multiple small numbers together (a hash), or does it make no difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key differences between a composite index (an index on `(a, b)`) and an index on a hash function are:

- with a composite index PostgreSQL can make decisions based on the statistics it keeps for each individual column; and
- in a composite index you can query the index efficiently for just `a`. You can *not* query it for just `b`, though.

On the other hand, with an index on `a::bigint << 32 + b`, ie a 64-bit single-element index that combines the values of `a` and `b`, you can only use it when you have both `a` and `b`. The same is true of an index on `some_hash_function(a,b)`.

There can be a big advantage to an index on the hash of the value, in that it makes the index a lot smaller at the cost of reduced selectivity and the need to re-check the condition with something like:

```
WHERE some_hash_function(a,b) = some_hash_function(42,3) AND (a = 42 AND b = 3)
```

There is a significant possibility you neglected to consider, though: two separate indexes on `a` and `b`. PostgreSQL can combine these in a bitmap index scan or use them separately, whatever's more appropriate for the query. This is usually the best option for two loosely related and mostly uncorrelated values.

Given the example:

```
CREATE TABLE demoab(a integer, b integer);

INSERT INTO demoab(a, b)
SELECT a, b from generate_series(1,1000) a 
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,1000) b;

CREATE INDEX demoab_a ON demoab(a);
CREATE INDEX demoab_b ON demoab(b);
CREATE INDEX demoab_ab ON demoab(a,b);
CREATE INDEX demoab_ab_shifted ON demoab ((a::bigint << 32 + b));
ANALYZE demoab;

CREATE TABLE demob AS SELECT DISTINCT b FROM demoab ;
CREATE TABLE demoa AS SELECT DISTINCT a FROM demoab ;
ALTER TABLE demoa ADD PRIMARY KEY (a);
ALTER TABLE demob ADD PRIMARY KEY (b);
```

Different query approaches:

```
regress=> explain analyze SELECT * FROM demoab WHERE a = 42 AND b = 3;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using demoab_ab on demoab  (cost=0.00..8.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.034..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((a = 42) AND (b = 3))
 Total runtime: 0.088 ms
(3 rows)


regress=> explain analyze SELECT * FROM demoab WHERE b = 3;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on demoab  (cost=19.85..2358.66 rows=967 width=8) (actual time=1.089..4.636 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (b = 3)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on demoab_b  (cost=0.00..19.61 rows=967 width=0) (actual time=0.661..0.661 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (b = 3)
 Total runtime: 4.820 ms
(5 rows)

regress=> explain analyze SELECT * FROM demoab WHERE a = 42;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using demoab_a on demoab  (cost=0.00..37.19 rows=962 width=8) (actual time=0.155..0.751 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (a = 42)
 Total runtime: 0.929 ms
(3 rows)

regress=> explain analyze SELECT * FROM demoab WHERE (a::bigint << 32 + b) = (42::bigint << 32 + 3);
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on demoab  (cost=4.69..157.67 rows=41 width=8) (actual time=0.260..0.495 rows=94 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((a)::bigint << (32 + b)) = 1443109011456::bigint)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on demoab_ab_shifted  (cost=0.00..4.67 rows=41 width=0) (actual time=0.232..0.232 rows=94 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((a)::bigint << (32 + b)) = 1443109011456::bigint)
 Total runtime: 0.584 ms
(5 rows)
```

Here, the composite index on `(a,b)` would be a *clear win* because it's able to use an index only scan to get the tuple directly, but it wouldn't be likely to in reality where you'll be fetching values from non-indexed columns. Because of that I ran `SET enable_indexscan = off` for these tests.

Rather surprisingly, the index sizes are the same:

```
regress=> SELECT 
pg_relation_size('demoab_ab') AS shifted, 
pg_relation_size('demoab_ab') AS ab, 
pg_relation_size('demoab_a') AS a, 
pg_relation_size('demoab_b') AS b;
 shifted  |    ab    |    a     |    b     
----------+----------+----------+----------
 22487040 | 22487040 | 22487040 | 22487040
(1 row)
```

I expected the single-value indexes to need considerably less space. Alignment requirements explain some of it, but it's still rather an unexpected result to me.

In the case of the join @wildplasser asked about:

```
regress=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT demoa.a, demob.b 
FROM demoab 
INNER JOIN demoa ON (demoa.a = demoab.a) 
INNER JOIN demob ON (demob.b = demoab.b) 
WHERE demoa.a = 100 AND demob.b = 500;

                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..24.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.121..0.126 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.089..0.092 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using demoab_ab on demoab  (cost=0.00..8.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((a = 100) AND (b = 500))
         ->  Index Scan using demoa_pkey on demoa  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (a = 100)
   ->  Index Scan using demob_pkey on demob  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (b = 500)
 Total runtime: 0.203 ms
(9 rows)
```

shows that in this case PostgreSQL is preferring the composite index on (a, b). This will not be the case if you're only joining on `b` though:

```
regress=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT demoab.a, demoab.b 
FROM demoab 
INNER JOIN demob ON (demob.b = demoab.b) 
WHERE demob.b = 500;
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=19.85..2376.59 rows=967 width=8) (actual time=0.935..3.653 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using demob_pkey on demob  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (b = 500)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on demoab  (cost=19.85..2358.66 rows=967 width=8) (actual time=0.897..3.123 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (b = 500)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on demoab_b  (cost=0.00..19.61 rows=967 width=0) (actual time=0.436..0.436 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (b = 500)
 Total runtime: 3.834 ms
(8 rows)
```

You'll note that any functional hash index won't be useful here. So for that reason, I recommend going for a composite index on `(a,b)` plus a secondary index on just `(b)` if you need it.

In terms of uniqueness, you'll find it informative to look at `pg_catalog.pg_stat`. There, you'll see that *PostgreSQL doesn't maintain statistics on individual indexes*, only on the heap columns that are indexed. In this case:

```
regress=> select tablename, attname, n_distinct, correlation 
from pg_stats where tablename like 'demo%';
     tablename     | attname | n_distinct | correlation 
-------------------+---------+------------+-------------
 demoab            | a       |       1000 |           1
 demoab            | b       |       1000 |   0.0105023
 demoab_ab_shifted | expr    |      21593 |   0.0175595
 demob             | b       |         -1 |    0.021045
 demoa             | a       |         -1 |    0.021045
(5 rows)
```

it doesn't look like Pg will see any significant difference between the hashed/combined approach and two  discrete, independent values.

Comment: I will always know a and b, and never query only b. So I would like to know which pattern is most likely to force an index scan, and which pattern would result in a faster scan.

Comment: Could you point me do some documentation on the bitmap index scan. Although this won't suit my particular query, I'm interested to see how this mechanism works.

Comment: The _faster scan_ is futile if you intend to retrieve one {a,b} tuple, and know a and b exactly. But things get different when the query could possibly yield more than one result row. And how about joining with two other tables, one of them on a and the other on b ?

Comment: @wildplasser Good question. I don't think a composite index can be used for the b-side of the join, though I think I'll test that out quickly to be sure.

Comment: But the conclusion would be: it is good for the query generator to **know** that {a,b} are independent keyfields. Combining their values into one variable (or function) will only hide this fact. (a kind of Hilbert's hotel with randomised/hashed room numbers ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser I think the bigger issue is that there are lots of situations where the planner just can't make use of a hashed or functional form. So for that reason alone I'd stick to a composite index.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks for this. You said "Here, the composite index on (a,b) would be a clear win because it's able to use an index only scan to get the tuple directly..." I don't see why the hashed value wouldn't be the same? In fact, what I had in mind was to *combine* the two columns into 1 hash column, so as far as PG was concerned, there is only 1 column. The << | would occur on the client. Surely this should be faster and yield better cardinality?

Comment: @IanC It *might* be, but testing so far suggests otherwise, and it costs you the flexibility of using the composite index as a free index on just `a` when you need that. All I can say at this point is "benchmark, test, and see". That's what these things always come down to anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If Col1 and Col2 are independent fields, why combining? It won't save any space. Just stick to  the atomicity principle of database.

Comment: I'm not asking about space. I'm asking about uniqueness of index, which influences the query execution plan.

Comment: @lanC Single index is simple, thus is helpful for query optimization. But postgresql is better than other DB in supporting multi-dimensional index. I think it depends on how COl1 and Col2 related. If Col1 and Col2 is highly related, thus combining them means something, for example if Col1 and Col2 is (x, y) coordinate of a point, I recommand multi-dimensional index. If combining of Col1 and COl2 means nothing, Simply single index compatibility without atomicity is not worth trying.

Comment: Thanks. There is a double negative in your comment, so I don't understand the comparison you make. Let's say Col1 and Col2 are loosely related (price, weight), are you saying the only advantage of combining them is query simplicity? I would also think it's faster to look up 1 number than 2.

Comment: @lanC I am not saying Combing them will make query simpler, on the contrary, it makes query more complex in your application code. It only makes query index simpler, or shorter, because DB do less things for you. It may help improve DB side performance by combining fields, but it increase application side complexity. That is a trade-off between DB and application.

Comment: @lanC If in your query, there is any sub query on just Col1 or Col2, you should not combine them.

Comment: This I understand. However, I still want to know if combining affects the cardinality.

Comment: @lanC I want to know that, too. Just do some mesurement about these two solution. I'll do it later. If you get some real world mesurement result, let me know.

Comment: The answer is that the values of composite indexes are concatenated into one value, so it makes no difference.